# Why do monitor goes off first before CPU goes off?

Tags: windows-10, cpu

After shutting down of windows 10, Why monitor goes off first before CPU goes off? I think both should goes off at a time.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. To get a more positive response to a question, I recommend showing that you have done some of your own research first and showing that the behavior you're seeing is not expected. Stating that you simply don't think something should be a certain way might be interpreted more as opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, fair question.

We can start with some terminology.  I totally understand why you would refer to your monitor as a desktop; When people refer to "an icon on the desktop", that is where you would look to see it.

The term of art "desktop", however refers to a box that might be situated on top of a desk (a desk-top, as it were), and that I think you are referring to as a CPU.

The CPU (central processing unit, or processor, often made by Intel or AMD these days) does a lot of the data processing on a typical computer.  Often it will have its own fan, and it will be attached to the motherboard, which is a circuit board inside the case of the computer that you plug other cards or devices into (e.g. the CPU, graphics cards, USB devices, etc.).  These "other cards" used to be referred to as "daughter-boards" if you go far enough back in time (thus "mother")

Now to the answer.

Your monitor almost certainly has its own power, but takes its cues about turning on or off from the video card that is plugged into the motherboard of your computer.  It does this for power saving, so that when you lock the screen and walk away with the computer on, the computer can shut down the screen to avoid wasting power.

The primary component of the computer is the motherboard.  It doesn't function well without the CPU, and doesn't do all that you need it to do without the other components (from the keyboard to the monitor), but it can do things all on its own (even if that just means beeping).

What is almost certainly happening is that the operating system (Windows) is working to shut down the system cleanly, including all of the various components, like the video drivers that control the monitor.

What is nevertheless true is that such a monitor cannot stay on after the motherboard (in the component typically referred to as the computer, be it desktop or laptop) turns off, and *may* turn off before the motherboard does.

I hope this is useful information.

Comment: If I remember correctly Windows 10 does by default not shut down the whole system cleanly but instead hibernates the kernel memory ("fast start" or similar called). And when using hibernate it is pretty normal that first the monitor goes off and then the hibernation is triggered.